# React: Object properties added in LoadDataFrom Server are undefined in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m new to React and have a problem I don’t understand.  My data is an array of objects with properties of “sketches” (name, number of “links”, number of “nodes”, and other stuff) from a JSON file.  I load the data and send some of it to a list component that I filter by the number of links and nodes.  All that works fine.  My problem is that I want to add an ID number to what I send to the filtered list (for returning a click).  Here is the LoadDataFrom Server part of my code:

```
const MyApp = React.createClass({  
  loadDataFromServer: function() {  
    $.ajax({                     
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
        const sketz = [];
        for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          const sid = i;
          sketz[i] = {sid: sid,
            name: data[i].name,
            numberOflinks: data[i].numberOflinks,
            numberOfnodes: data[i].numberOfnodes
         };
        }
        this.setState({
          sketches: sketz
        })
      }.bind(this),
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },   .....
```

The problem is that, while any property value from data gets to the list component OK, anything else I try to add, such as “sid”, but any other property and value that did not come from data, shows up in the list component as undefined.  I have checked sketches in LoadDataFromServer and the assigned IDs are there, but they are gone in the list.  I am really not understanding why the sketches object array behaves this way and would like to (1) understand why, and (2) know how do this correctly.  Thanks!

Added by request: the list component (actually, two components).  It follows the code used in the React docs under the heading of Thinking in React, where it is for a table, not an unordered list.  The first console.log (for the ID) gives undefined; the second gives the correct name for each pass through the forEach.

```
const SketchList = React.createClass({ 
  render: function() {
    const rows = [];
    const lf = this.props.numlnk;    // "link filter"
    const nf = this.props.numnde;   // "node filter"
    this.props.sketches.forEach(function(sketch) {
      console.log('in sketch, ID is ' + sketch.sid);
      console.log('in sketch, name is ' + sketch.name);
      if(lf == 0 || lf == sketch.numberOflinks) {
        if (nf == 0 || nf == sketch.numberOfnodes) {
          rows.push(<SketchRow 
            sketch={sketch} 
            key={sketch.name}
          />);
        }
      }
    });
    return (
      <div className="row voffset3 divcolor">
        <ul className="nobull mar-left list-scroll">
          {rows}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const SketchRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li >
        {
          this.props.sketch.name
        }
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: To clarify, which properties are showing up as `undefined`?

Comment: can you provide your list component

Comment: @Isiah: Per the added component code, "sid" is undefined while "name", "numberOflinks", and "numberOfnodes" have the values set in LoadData... However, any other name: value pair that I add in LoadData... also shows up as undefined.

Comment: Can I see your `render` function for `MyApp`? It could be that the data isn't available on first render, because the data requested hasn't gotten back yet.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you're only using jQuery's `ajax`, check out [some of the AJAX microlibs](http://microjs.com/#ajax) and the [`fetch` polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch). No need to download 20kb+ of data just for some simple AJAX sugar IMO.

Comment: @Isiah: You sent me in the right direction and I found some earlier code I hadn't updated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Isiah.  OPERATOR ERROR. I was resetting sketches to data in the render, left over from an earlier version where I was only working out the filtered list.